# Opencv MSER detectRegions C++ Vs. Python

Tags: python, c++, opencv, mser

I am porting Python program to C++, which uses MSER (OpenCV) detectRegions. I am noticing strange behavior that number of MSER regions detected by C++ program is significantly lower than Python one. I am using same image as a input to both of them and performing identical preprocessing steps before calling detectRegions. For particular example image, number of MSER areas detected by Python program were 6620, but after porting to C++ I am getting only 1164.

Only difference at my end is that for Python, I am using x64 version of cv2.pyd (\build\python\2.7\x64), while for C++ I am using x86 (\build\x86\vc12).

For both programs, following steps are performed:

1. Read image using imread
2. Convert to gray scale using cvtColor with COLOR_BGR2GRAY
3. Perform histogram equalization:

   ```
   a. CLAHE object is created using clipLimit=2.0, tileGridSize - 8x8

   b. apply CLAHE on gray image
   ```
4. Get height and width of image.
5. Scale image to 600X800 SVGA size

   a. if width > height then scale = width / 800.0

   b. else scale = height / 600.0

   c. Use 'resize' with above scaling factor 'scale'
6. Create MSER object
7. setDelta(4)
8. Call detectRegions

Comment: I just faced with similar difference. Actually in my case there is no any preprocessing. I am just reading the same image and saving all the detected regions of the image. C++ version gives me more accurate result rather than python for text extraction from the image.

I am also very interested in the answer of this question!

Comment: The python module of OpenCV is binded from the C++ one. If you see some difference between C++ and Python it might be because a parameter may have rewrite in the MSER implementation but this is quite unlikely, or a flag or a preprocessing that you do before calling the MSER desctiptor that you forget to set or which have a slightly different behaviour on the image but enough to influence MSER e.g. the order of the channels, a normalization,...